# Get correct data from Codeigniter query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I'm currently trying to get an array from my database using codeigniter active record which something I do often but I'm currently having a problem getting the correct data.

There is 4 records which should be getting returned to my controller from my model. At the moment all records from the table are being returned.

I'm using a `foreach` loop within my query as the queries `where`/`or_where` clause can be many values. This is where the problem lies as I think it bypasses the foreach and get's all records without looking at the where clause.

My question is regarding what seems to be the problem with the 2nd example?

**WORKING**

**The following code gets the desired 4 records which should be returned:**

```
public function get_most_relevant($user){

    $categories = $this->get_users_most_common_categories($user);

    $this->db->order_by('posts.date_created','DESC');
    $this->db->limit(25);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->select('posts.image_name as post_image');
    $this->db->select('posts.random_string as post_string');
    $this->db->select('posts.date_created as post_creation');
    $this->db->join('users', 'posts.user_string = users.random_string','left'); 
    $this->db->where('category_string', 'cCU8oEQHYLWP');
    $this->db->or_where('category_string', '8RfRDWrG5QB7');

    $posts = $this->db->get();

    return $posts;

}
```

**NOT WORKING**

**The following code gets all records from the table:**

It appears to be bypassing the `foreach` and going straight to the `get()`.

```
public function get_most_relevant($user){

    $categories = $this->get_users_most_common_categories($user);
    $i = 0;

    $this->db->order_by('posts.date_created','DESC');
    $this->db->limit(25);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->select('posts.image_name as post_image');
    $this->db->select('posts.random_string as post_string');
    $this->db->select('posts.date_created as post_creation');
    $this->db->join('users', 'posts.user_string = users.random_string','left'); 

    foreach($categories->result_array() as $category){
        if($i == 0){
            $this->db->where( array('category_string' => $category['category_string'], 'published' => '1') );
        }else{
            $this->db->or_where( array('category_string' => $category['category_string'], 'published' => '1') );
        }   
        $i++;
    }

    $posts = $this->db->get();

    return $posts;

}
```

**$this->get_users_most_common_categories($user) code**

```
public function get_users_most_common_categories($user){

    $categories = $this->db->query("SELECT category_string, COUNT(category_string) AS category_occurence FROM views WHERE user_string = '".$user."' OR ip_address = '".$user."' GROUP BY category_string ORDER BY category_occurence DESC");

    return $categories;

}
```

**$this->get_users_most_common_categories($user) return**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [category_string] => cCU8oEQHYLWP
        [category_occurence] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [category_string] => 8RfRDWrG5QB7
        [category_occurence] => 1
    )

)
```

**QUERY OUTPUT**

SELECT *, `posts`.`image_name` as post_image, `posts`.`random_string` as post_string, `posts`.`date_created` as post_creation FROM (`posts`) LEFT JOIN `users` ON `posts`.`user_string` = `users`.`random_string` WHERE `category_string` = 'cCU8oEQHYLWP' AND `published` = '1' OR `category_string` = '8RfRDWrG5QB7' OR `published` = '1' ORDER BY `posts`.`date_created` DESC LIMIT 25

Thanks for your help in advance, it is much appreciated.

Comment: does `$categories->result_array()` return a non-empty array?

Comment: @DavidNormington not sure what you mean by non-empty array but view my edits, thanks.

Comment: @DavidNormington It appears to be adding an `OR` instead of `AND` in between `'category_string' = '8RfRDWrG5QB7' OR 'published' = '1'`, could you have a look at my edit where I've added the query?

Comment: It may be a bug. You could try writing that part of the query as a string which you can pass to `where` and `or_where`:

`$this->db->where("(category_string = ".$category['category_string']." AND published = '1')");`

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select - see `where` part 4 Custom String.

Comment: @DavidNormington That's exactly what it was but I've got the query working now which has made me happy. Feel free to create an answer and I'll accept, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a bug. You could try writing that part of the query as a string which you can pass to `where` and `or_where`:

```
foreach($categories->result_array() as $category){
    $query = "(category_string = ".$category['category_string']." AND published = '1')";

    if($i == 0){
        $this->db->where($query);
    }else{
        $this->db->or_where($query);
    }   
    $i++;
}
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/… - see where part 4 Custom String

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do to find out where did you go wrong in your query is to use the **last_query** function of the CI DB driver. It returns the last SQL string that was run. You can then execute that query into your database client and adjust it until you get the result that you want.

```
$posts = $this->db->get();
$sql = $this->db->last_query();
echo $sql;
```

Comment: It appears to be adding an `OR` instead of `AND` in between `'category_string' = '8RfRDWrG5QB7' OR 'published' = '1'`, could you have a look at my edit where I've added the query?

Comment: instead of `$this->db->or_where()` use `$this->db->where()`